# how do vision transformers deal with input images with different sizes?

Tags: computer-vision, transformer-model, vision-transformer

I want to train a vision transformer with progressive learning which is used in EffientNetV2. Is there any way to do this in a transformer model?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.